# Google Cloud Platform Java - Maven Deploy targets wrong project

Tags: java, maven, gcloud, platform

I am trying to deploy a sample project to test out the google cloud's java environment. For some reason, the wrong version of my gcloud project is being attempted.

Command:
    **mvn appengine:deploy -DprojectID=test-projectId123**

```
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (default-cli) < package @ bookshelf-2 <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (default-cli) @ bookshelf-2 ---
[INFO] Deleting the staging directory: /Users/jeffgriffith/Projects/getting-started-java/bookshelf/2-structured-data/target/appengine-staging
[INFO] Staging the application to: /Users/jeffgriffith/Projects/getting-started-java/bookshelf/2-structured-data/target/appengine-staging
[INFO] Detected App Engine flexible environment application.
Apr 23, 2017 11:02:21 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: /Users/jeffgriffith/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy /Users/jeffgriffith/Projects/getting-started-java/bookshelf/2-structured-data/target/appengine-staging/app.yaml --quiet
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [403] The client project has been deleted.
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: Details: [
[INFO] GCLOUD:   [
[INFO] GCLOUD:     {
[INFO] GCLOUD:       "@type":         
                          "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure",
[INFO] GCLOUD:       "violations": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:         {
[INFO] GCLOUD:           "description": "The client project has been deleted.",
[INFO] GCLOUD:           "subject": "project:289370843929"
[INFO] GCLOUD:         }
[INFO] GCLOUD:       ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:     }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   ]
[INFO] GCLOUD: ]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The project does exist**

Answer (score 1):

gcloud init with updated settings solved the problem